# Probability density function estimation?

Tags: probability, density-function

This is a question from a textbook titled Probability and Stochastic Processes by Leo Breiman.
This is problem 12 of Chapter I of the book.

A current is switched on sometime "at random" during a day. Then it is switched off "at random" between the time current is switched on and the end of the day. Let the outcome of the experiments be these two times.

**Find appropriate density function f(x,y)?**

For this part, I assumed it to be a uniform density function and found its value of it by integrating over the region  $$ 0 \le x \le 24   \ {\rm and} \ x \le y \le 24 $$

$$  \iint_A c \,dx\,dy $$

where A is the interval given above.

**Evaluate the probability that the current was on at least half the day.**

For the second part, I evaluated integral over $$ 12 \le x \le 24   \ {\rm and} \ x \le y \le 24 $$.

Is my approach correct because my answer is far from what is mentioned in the book?

Comment: Please show all of your work, including the *answer* that you derived, regardless of whether *your* answer is correct.

Comment: @user2661923 I will edit that, but I just wanted to know whether my approach is correct or not

Comment: Not the correct approach. Hint for 1: $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) f_{X}(x)$. For part 2: $y-x$ is the time the current is on.